# Python genfromtxt in VS Code doesn't find the txt

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to read a .txt file that is in the same folder as my python execution directory with Visual Code. However, Visual Code does not find the file at all. I already checked with the command os.getcwd () that I am in the same directory as the .txt file, however, the program has the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: OSError
t43_2_rl1_str_Idvg_Vds_4_IV0.txt not found.
File "/home/User/Desktop/Directory/Trans/L_VT_I_CTE.py", line 5, in lecture
data = np.genfromtxt(name,dtype='float')
```

If I print `os.getcws` I get:

```
/home/User/Desktop/Directory
```

That is the same directory... I tried to change the launch.json, including the cwd, but it didn't work... Even trying to execute the file in ubuntu terminal, I got the same error...

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my error... I just add change the filename to `"Trans/t43_2_rl1_str_Idvg_Vds_4_IV0.txt"` and it did work!

Thank you =)